# How to show that $f_n(x)=1-x^n$ converges to a set valued function, $f(x)$, which takes 1 for $x\in[0,1)$ but takes $[0,1]$ at $x=1$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

It seems that $f_n(x)=1-x^n$ converges to $f(x)$ such that \begin{eqnarray*} f(x)&=&1~~\text{for}~~x\in[0,1)\\ &=& [0,1]~~\text{for}~~x=1.\end{eqnarray*}

I wonder if it is correct or not. If it is, how to show this convergence?

Comment: $x^n$ converges to $0$ for $|x|<1$ and to $1$ for $x=1$. In the other cases, it diverges.

Comment: How are you getting this limit at 1?

Comment: Surely $f(1)$ is identically equal to $0$ for all $n$? How on earth would you say it is $[0,1]$? What would that even mean?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers. What I was thinking is not correct in the end. The reason why I was thinking in this way is the graph of $f_n(x)$ with a large $n$ looks like $f(x)$ defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $0\le x<1$ we have $\lim _{n\to \infty} x^n =0$ therefore $1-x^n \to 1$

On the other hand for $x=1$ we have $1-x^n=0$ so the limit is $0$